# Calculate frequency across columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have meeting attendance data currently formatted as lists of ID numbers of the members present at each meeting:

```
9/21/13 | 9/22/13 | 9/23/13
123456  | 408437  | 123456
408437  | 349343  | 349343  
349343  | 408437  |
        | 739848  |
```

I'd like to get those into something like this

```
ID Numbr| 9/21/13 | 9/22/13 | 9/23/13 
123456  | 1       | 0       | 1
408437  | 1       | 1       | 0
349343  | 1       | 1       | 1
739848  | 0       | 1       | 0
ETC...
```

I've created a pivot table with the meeting dates in the row section and the "Count of [meeting date]" in the value section, however counts straight across the rows, rather than looking for each ID number in each column. Does anyone have suggestions or a better way to do this?

Comment: In the `9/22/2013` column, you have 408437 listed twice. Should this be 2 in your second example, or is the second example just listing boolean values of "ID # attended the meeting on this date, true or false?" Also, how much do you *need* a solution using pivot tables? This is trivial to accomplish with COUNTIF, but that might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be outside of what you can change, but recording the data in a different matter would make it easier for data analysis.

```
Recording Attendence like this:
Date        Attendee
9/21/2013   123456
9/21/2013   408437
9/21/2013   349343
9/22/2013   408437
9/22/2013   349343
9/22/2013   408437
9/22/2013   739848
9/23/2013   123456
9/23/2013   349343
```

Then pivoting this (with Date in row labels, Attendee in column labels, and Count Of Attendee in Values) will give you the desired output.